# Cosa significa "è gaudio" in questo contesto

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

Questa frase è tratta da "Carlo Martello ritorna dalla battaglia di Poitiers" di De André:

> Deh, cavaliere, non v'accostate, già ad altri **è gaudio** quel che cercate

Descrive il momento in cui la fanciulla dà il due di picche al Re in un primo momento, che non vede una donna da molto tempo per via della guerra.

Cosa significa in questo caso "è gaudio"; so che "gaudio" [significa "gioia intensa"](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/gaudio/), ma non riesco  ad inquadrarlo bene nel contesto.

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE, @gRizzlyGR!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mi sembra che la fanciulla stia dicendo al Re di non avvicinarsi a lei e che quello che lui cerca (il piacere, la gioia (gaudio) di stare con una fanciulla) è cosa già conosciuta  da altri.

Penso che De André abbia voluto usare un linguaggio ricercato dato il contesto della vicenda. 'Gaudio' non è un termine molto comune tranne che nel modo di dire 'mal comune mezzo gaudio'.

[Gaudio](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/gaudio/): Treccani.it

> - ***Con sign. più generico, gioia, piacere***, soprattutto nel prov. *mal comune mezzo g.*, le sofferenze sembrano meno gravi quando sono divise con altri. Raro il plur., e solo in frasi di tono elevato: *ore di gaudii Lunghe ci son davanti* (D’Annunzio).

Comment: Grazie. Giusto per chiarifica, il testo l'ha scritto Paolo Villaggio.

Comment: @gRizzlyGR: in effetti, come spiegato __[qui](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Il_fannullone/Carlo_Martello_ritorna_dalla_battaglia_di_Poitiers)__! Non lo sapevo, e credo sia poco noto (come è poco noto che alcune canzoni di De André siano in realtà traduzioni o adattamenti). Grazie

Answer (score 6):

Io lo interpreto come un modo molto arzigogolato di dire che è sposata: *quel che cercate* (=giacere con lei) *è già gaudio ad altri* (=è un piacere che spetta già ad un'altra persona, il marito).

Comment: Interessante punto di vista, non ci avevo pensato.

Answer (score 3):

Io intenderei gaudio come godimento, parafrasando, quindi, *è godimento altrui ciò che lei cerca*. In questo modo si sottolinea anche l'assonanza tra le due parole.